# Почему не сохраняется файл в Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx

Делаю дизайн java приложения в Gluon Scene Builder

Сохраняю в текущий fxml файл в папку своего проекта, но файл не перезаписывается, все остается как и прежде. Также пытаюсь сохранить fxml файл в Scene Builder на жесткий диск,файл не сохраняется. В чем может быть причина? Это баг Scene Builder?

Мой дефолтный fxml файл проекта:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
styleClass="background" stylesheets="@Style.css" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.0">
<children>
  <AnchorPane prefHeight="247.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="403.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" 
AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
        <Label layoutX="24.0" layoutY="27.0" styleClass="text-label" 
stylesheets="@Style.css" text="Enter The Name" />
        <TextField layoutX="340.0" layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="35.0" 
prefWidth="240.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="340.0" 
AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="24.0" />
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
 </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Может у Scene Builder нет прав на запись в папку проекта.

Comment: а как это посмотреть?

Comment: Какая у вас установлена ОС?

Comment: операционная система  windows 10

Comment: Запустите билдер от админа и попробуйте создать новый файл и отредактировать существующий, если все получилось проблема была с правами, если нет то проблема с билдером.